# If we do any modification in author environment will it be changed in publish environment? if it is changed how it works in backend? in cq5

Tags: aem

In Cq5,
If we do any modification in author environment will it be changed in publish environment? if it is changed how it works in backend?

Comment: Please don't ask your question in the subject line of the question.  It should be a summary, not your entire question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, changes in the author environment do not automatically change the publish environment. For example, changes that content authors make to pages will not be reflected on publish until the page is activated.

You'll see "Activate" buttons and menu items in tools like site admin, but the process is called replication. See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/replication.html